# using applymap method to color cells based on condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I would like to color some cells (in a data frame) based on their content using pandas, I did some tries but with no required results

this is my last failed try :

```
import pandas as pd
import dataframe_image as dfi
df = pd.read_excel('splice traitment.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet4', usecols="B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K")

def color_cells(val):
    color = 'red' if val == 7 else ''
    return 'background-color: {}'.format(color)

df.style.applymap(color_cells)
dfi.export(df,"table.png")
```

**Thank you very much**

Answer (score 0):

You can pass styled DataFrame to `export` method:

```
dfi.export(df.style.applymap(color_cells),"table.png")
```

Or asign to variable `styled`:

```
styled = df.style.applymap(color_cells)
dfi.export(styled,"table.png")
```